# Converting unified version in python using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to convert a unified version format to the following in python

Examples:

- `<2.2.1 || >=4.0.0 < 4.1.9`
  should be
  `<2.2.1 || (>=4.0.0 && <4.1.9)`
- `>=7.0.23 <7.0.91 || >=8.5.0 <8.5.34 || >=9.0.0 <9.0.12`
  should be
  `(>=7.0.23 && <7.0.91) || (>=8.5.0 && <8.5.34) || (>=9.0.0 && <9.0.12)`
- `<2.7.9.4 || >=2.8.0 <2.8.11.2 || >=2.9.0 <2.9.6`
  should be
  `(>=0 && <2.7.9.4) || (>=2.8.0 && <2.8.11.2) || (>=2.9.0 && <2.9.6)`

tried the following, it works but messy:

```
def rchop(thestring, ending):
  if thestring.endswith(ending):
    return thestring[:-len(ending)]
return thestring

ver = "<2.7.9.4 || >=2.8.0 <2.8.11.2 || >=2.9.0 <2.9.6"
split_ver = ver.split('||')
list_data = []
for version in split_ver:
   version = version.rstrip()
   version = version.lstrip()
   vv = version.replace(" ", " && ")
   list_data.append(vv)
print(list_data)

new_list = []
for data in list_data:
 if "&&" not in data and "=0" not in data and ">=" not in data:
   new_data = "(>=0 && " + data + ")"
   new_list.append(new_data)
 else:
   new_data1 = new_list.append("("+data+")")

final_list = []
for items in new_list:
  data = final_list.append(items + " || ")

now_data = [''.join(final_list[:])]
data1 = rchop(now_data[0], ' || ')
print(data1)
```

Comment: May we know what have you tried and what problems you faced?

Comment: It is unclear what the requirement is here, would you please put some test code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: the requirements here is that the script I'm using produces buggy version format, so I'm trying to fix it using a regular expression by adding proper parentheses and proper && as the above conversions.

Comment: I added the code @boonwj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you need regex for this. Seems like you could just split the strings a couple times, reformat the parts and then join them back together to match your example outputs (assuming that the example output where you show `<2.2.1 || (>=4.0.0 && <4.1.9)` is a typo and it should actually follow the pattern of the other similar example and be `(>=0 && <2.2.1) || (>=4.0.0 && <4.1.9)` instead.

Maybe there are more edge cases that don't follow the example patterns, but the below should at least give you a simpler starting place to work from.

```
def version_formatter(text):
    raw = [t.strip().split() for t in text.split('||')]
    formatted = [f'({r[0]} && {r[1]})' if len(r) == 2 else f'(>=0 && {r[0]})' for r in raw]
    return ' || '.join(formatted)

tests = ['<2.2.1 || >=4.0.0 <4.1.9', '>=7.0.23 <7.0.91 || >=8.5.0 <8.5.34 || >=9.0.0 <9.0.12', '<2.7.9.4 || >=2.8.0 <2.8.11.2 || >=2.9.0 <2.9.6']

for test in tests:
    result = version_formatter(test)
    print(result)

# OUTPUT
# (>=0 && <2.2.1) || (>=4.0.0 && <4.1.9)
# (>=7.0.23 && <7.0.91) || (>=8.5.0 && <8.5.34) || (>=9.0.0 && <9.0.12)
# (>=0 && <2.7.9.4) || (>=2.8.0 && <2.8.11.2) || (>=2.9.0 && <2.9.6)
```